# Windows 10 How to remove the shared folder icon

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, sharing

Can't seem to figure out how to remove these little annoying icons that show on the two HDDs I've shared over LAN. Any ideas? 
Changing the HDD icon will only do that, and the two people will stay there. I can't find a way to change icons for the groups that I'm sharing it with either, as I was hoping if I just changed the icon to the part of the HDD that is missing it will look okay, or an `.ico` that's transparent. 
The image link below shows what I mean.

Icons on the HDD:

[image]

Was hoping I could change these icons to get around it:

[image]

Comment: In order to remove those icons you would have to stop sharing those locations. You could also replace the File Explorer shell with a third-party solution of your choice.  The icons cannot be changed, they could be replaced, but that involves patching signed system files which is an absolutely horrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

Open Regedit and make a string at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons`

The string should be named "28".

Enter its value as any blank Icon file. Maybe `shell32.dll,-50`

Rebuild the icon cache and restart the pc or just Explorer.